# Efficiently approximating the integral of $\operatorname{erf}(x y) \exp(-x^2)$

Tags: integration, polynomials, approximation, gaussian-integral, chebyshev-polynomials

I need to efficiently approximate this integral which represents the Gaussian-weighted area of a right triangle whose three points are the origin plus two points that form a vertical "edge", one of which is the edge's nearest point to the origin at $y=0$ and the other, the corner, which is at the same value of $x$. This integral has two inputs, $x$ which is the distance to the edge and $s$ which is the slope from the origin to the corner point. To help with avoiding high degree components the slope needs be no larger than 1 (if the slope is originally larger than 1 the inputs are swapped and the result used to subtract to $\operatorname{erf}(x)\operatorname{erf}(s)$).

$$\int_0^x \frac{\operatorname{erf}(t s) \exp(-t^2)}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\, dt$$

I tried to approximate it in the $x = [-3 , 3], s = [-1 , 1]$ range with a simple 2D Chebyshev approximation, however to achieve my desired maximum absolute error of about $4\cdot10^{-5}$ I need about 31 coefficients in my 2D polynomial. That's a bit much, ideally I would be able to use fewer operations. I have tried to improve the situation by applying operations to the integral before fitting, such as the reciprocal, dividing by $x$ or $s$ or trying to somehow use the limits to gain some sort of advantage, like making a polynomial to interpolate between the limit at $s=0$ (which is $\frac{1-\exp(-x^2)}{2\pi}$) and the integral at $s=1$ (which is $\frac{{\operatorname{erf}(x)}^2}{8}$), or somehow use the limit at $x=\inf$ (which for my purposes is very close to what we have at $x=3$) which is $\frac{\arctan(s)}{2\pi}$, but this didn't help much in achieving more precision with fewer polynomial coefficients. Perhaps there is something clever that I didn't think of or something completely different than a mere polynomial that could be more efficient, perhaps a way to break the problem down into 1D steps.

[image: Graph]

Integral to approximate, shown with added contours. Yellow is positive, blue negative. Horizontal axis is $x = [-3,3]$, vertical is $s = [-1,1]$.

I'm aware that I could well segment the approximation into a table of small piecewise 2D polynomials, however due to the need to avoid table lookups and dynamic branching I'd rather keep it all in one piece. This integral is used to closely approximate the ideal graphical result of a concave or convex polygon convolved with a 2D Gaussian kernel by calculating the sum of the Gaussian-weighted areas of triangular subdivisions of the polygon, my current implementation works nicely but needs more precision and hopefully can be made more efficient.

Comment: Isn't the integral on $[-3,3]$ zero since the integrand is odd? Or what do you mean precisely?

Comment: I didn't mean that the integral would be evaluated from -3 to 3. It starts from 0 and goes to whatever x is, x being in the [-3,3] range. I'm not sure how to write that in notation.

Comment: I edited your formula. Is it what you meant? Note that because of the oddness of the integrand, you can focus on $0\leq x\leq 3$ and $0\leq s\leq 1$.

Comment: Perhaps, I'm not sure why we can't use $x$ everywhere though. And yes I agree about the symmetry, however since we're talking about polynomial approximation it's good to keep that symmetry in mind because it can be advantageous to approximate over the whole symmetrical range rather than one half of it.

Comment: Because the integration variable is a dummy variable. You cannot write $\int_0^x f(x)dx$. It does not make sense that $x$ ranges between $0$ and $x$. Are you coming from outside of mathematics?

Comment: Ah I see, thank you. Yes I'm a programmer, I have no formal mathematical education, so mathematical notation is a bit foreign to me.

Comment: If you are integrating a bivariate Gaussian over the triangle $(0.0),(x,0), (x, sx)$, the resulting integral should be from $0$ to $x/ \sqrt{2}$ , isn't it ?

Comment: Why $\frac{x}{\sqrt2}$? It has to go from $0$ to $x$ of course, why stop halfway?

Comment: From a programming point of view, with the given recursion formula, it became extremely unexpensive.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici which recursion formula do you mean?

Comment: $$b_0=\tan ^{-1}(s) \qquad \text{and} \qquad b_{n+1}=b_n+(-1)^{n}\frac{ s^{2 n-1}}{2 n-1}$$

Answer (score 3):

This is just a partial answer:

[Here](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/73B/jresv73Bn1p1_A1b.pdf) on section $4.3$ eq. $1$ is stated that:
$$ \int_{0}^{a} e^{-x^2}\text{erf}(x)\,dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4}\Big(\text{erf}(a)\Big)^2$$

So at least for $s=1$ you can use the square of an $\text{erf}$ function (as you mentioned).

Since for other values of $s$ you will have a projection of an always positive Gaussian exponential over different values for $\text{erf}(ts)$ which is a monotonically increasing function, but you won´t be able to solve them in closed form (at least with the mentioned formula), because integration by parts will always left different arguments on the exponential and the error function:
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big(\frac{1}{4}\text{erf}(x)\text{erf}(sx) \Big) = \frac{s\,\text{erf}(x)\,e^{-s^2x^2}-e^{-x^2}\,\text{erf}(sx)}{2\sqrt{\pi}}$$
In you shoes I could try with a weighted versions of the same squared error functions or something like $\frac{1}{4}\text{erf}(x)\text{erf}(sx)$ an then try to fit the difference function with a Taylor series or Padé Aproximant of low orders (like [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=PadeApproximant%5B+atan%28s%29%2F%282*pi%29+-+OwenT%5Bsqrt%282%29*x%2Cs%5D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C%7B4%2C5%7D%7D%5D) as example)... at least [Wolfram-Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int_0%5Ex+e%5E%28-t%5E2%29erf%28ts%29%2F%282+sqrt%28pi%29%29+dt+) gives a related-alike answer (but it also give a "$T$" function which I don´t know what it is, but maybe it will be easier than fitting the whole thing).

---

**Added later:**

Following the comments, since it looks like that the unknown function on Wolfram-Alpha was the Owen's T function, I search about it because of curiosity (I remember see it in some communications papers years ago at university), and by luck I found that surely it is Owen´s T function because of what it is said [here](https://sci-hub.se/10.1080/10652469.2015.1111889) on point $3$:
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\Big( T[z;a]\Big) = -\frac{e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\text{erf}\left(\frac{az}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$
$$ T[z;a] = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\limits_{-z}^{+\infty} e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}\text{erf}\left(\frac{at}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\,dt $$
where it can be easily seen the relation with the integral of the question.

[Here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/5142787_Fast_and_Accurate_Calculation_of_Owen%27s_T_Function/fulltext/57bb607a08ae51eef1f3d14e/Fast-and-Accurate-Calculation-of-Owens-T-Function.pdf) some ways to numerically calculate the Owen's T function are shown even with code, and some properties are also listed, like $T[-z;a] = T[z;a]$.

*Here I have delete a section that was mistaken.*

Applying the fundamental theorem of calculus to the differential formula, and that also $T[0,a] = \frac{\arctan(a)}{2\pi}$ (see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=OwenT%5B0%2Ca%5D)), it looks like **a proper development is**:
$$ \int\limits_{0}^{x} \frac{e^{-t^2}\text{erf}(st)}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\,dt = \frac{\arctan(s)}{2\pi}-T[\sqrt{2}\,x; s]$$
Which looks to work at least **for real positive $\mathbf{x,\,s}$** on Wolfram-Alpha, so forget about the previous result (droped since $T[0,a]\neq 1/2 \,\forall a$ - *already deleted section*), but it still starts integrating from some value different from zero, so keep caution. Also, $T[x,-a] = - T[x,a]$ so the result I give could behave differently from the result of Wolfram-Alpha for $s<0$, so I suggest you to keep using their result.

By the way, on Wolfram-Alpham the Owen´s T function is used as $\text{OwenT[x,a]}$.

I hope at least the founded formulas helps you. Good luck.

---

**Last attempt**
*Previously I give an attempt that indeed has a sign mistake that drops the results (as I was afraid). Since some properties was already typed and could help someone to answer the question, I will left them.*

Using what is show [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Owen%27s_T_function):
$$T[h;a] + T\left[ah; \frac{1}{a}\right] = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{2} \Phi(h)+\frac{1}{2} \Phi(ah)-\Phi(h)\Phi(ah),\, \text{if}\,s\geq 0 \\  \frac{1}{2} \Phi(h)+\frac{1}{2} \Phi(ah)-\Phi(h)\Phi(ah)-\frac{1}{2} ,\, \text{if}\,s < 0 \end{cases}$$
where the $\Phi(x)$ is the standard Gaussian cumulative distribution $\Phi(x) = \frac{1}{2}\left\{1+\text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \right\}$,

Noting that now using $h=\sqrt{2}x$ and $a=s$ then:
$$\frac{1}{2} \Phi(\sqrt{2}x)+\frac{1}{2} \Phi(\sqrt{2}sx)-\Phi(\sqrt{2}x)\Phi(\sqrt{2}sx) = \frac{1}{4}\left(1-\text{erf}(x)\text{erf}(sx)\right)$$

You will have again that (*here was where I made the sign mistake*):
$$ \begin{array}{r c l}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big(\frac{1}{4}\text{erf}(x)\text{erf}(sx) \Big) & = & \frac{s\,\text{erf}(x)\,e^{-s^2x^2}}{2\sqrt{\pi}}-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big(T[\sqrt{2}x;s]\Big) \\
& = & -\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big(T[\sqrt{2}sx;\frac{1}{s}]\Big)-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big(T[\sqrt{2}x;s]\Big)
\end{array} $$

So I hardly believe you will escape from the Owen's T functions, at least with a pencil. There are other different expressions for the Owen's T function on this [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_Gaussian_functions) but I didn´t find how to made simpler expression neither, but maybe they could be easier to become a series, just in case.

As a completely different scope, since Owens' T function is a probability distribution, a things I have used in the past (for other "weird" curves), is to fit another distribution for which the software I use already have calculation packages, one distribution which have result highly flexible is the three parameters [Generalized Gamma Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_gamma_distribution), maybe is suitable to approximate the Owen's T functions (but since your requirements of precision are highly accurate, I am no sure if it is going to work for you). Some software like R already have curve fitting for this distribution, maybe it is going to be fast to give it a try.

---

**Answering to a comment I made below:**

*Me: Did you tried series for $T\left[\sqrt{2}sx; \frac{1}{s}\right]$? They left only constants inside the $\text{erf}(x)$ functions when tested on point different from $x=0$, at least they look a bit easier to work with.*

*OP: I'm not sure what that would develop into.*

I am not really sure about this, but it is why I have asked the question. Since you are require an accurate a series representation, that also is efficient in the calculation times, I was thinking in exploring series from points $x \neq 0$.

Since you already have that for positive $x,s$:
$$ \int\limits_{0}^{x} \frac{e^{-t^2}\text{erf}(st)}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\,dt = \frac{\tan^{-1}(s)}{2\pi}-T[\sqrt{2}\,x; s]$$
The power series of the integral on the variable $x$ are affine/proportional to the series expansions of $T[\sqrt{2}x;s]$, so as you mentioned knowing it didn´t solve too much for your ambitions.

Playing with Wolfram-Alpha, the $\frac{\tan^{-1}(s)}{2\pi}-T[\sqrt{2}x;s]$ "looks similar" to the $\text{erf}(x)$ from positive $x$: not at zero, but near zero is like a linear function, and far from zero is like a constant, so to fit something in the place where it bends (the harder part), I was thinking on evaluating the series at $x\neq 0$, as example, I have arbitrarily choose $x=1$ (to avoid difficult squared terms and with luck, making easier factorization).

With this, on [Wolfram-Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=series+1%2F%282*pi%29*atan%28s%29+-+OwenT%5Bsqrt%282%29*x%2C+s%5D+at+x%3D1) the series expansion (Taylor) of $\frac{\tan^{-1}(s)}{2\pi}-T[\sqrt{2}x;s]$ on the variable $x$ at $x=1$ is given by a polynomial $f(s)+\mathbb{P}(x,s,\text{erf(s)})$.

Since the $\text{erf}(x)$ function is known for having slow converging series for $x>1$ (see on [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Taylor_series)), I was trying somehow to *remove part of its weirdness* before applying the series expansion.

I am not completely sure about the following formula because of sign issues with the variable $s$ ([here](https://sci-hub.se/10.1080/10652469.2015.1111889) a different convention than Wikipedia for the signs of the argument are used I think, this as example), but since it is not the main argument for this partial answer, for now supposed it is true: applying the properties of the Owen's T function $T[h;a]+T[ah;1/a]$ listed above, the integral could be represented as:
$$ \int\limits_{0}^{x} \frac{e^{-t^2}\text{erf}(st)}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\,dt = \frac{\tan^{-1}(s)}{2\pi}+\frac{1}{4}\text{erf}(x)\text{erf(sx)}-\frac{\text{sgn}(s)}{4}-T\left[\sqrt{2}sx; \frac{1}{s}\right]$$
Which looks more similar to the answer of [Wolfram-Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int_0%5Ex+e%5E%28-t%5E2%29erf%28st%29%2F%282*sqrt%28pi%29%29*dt), but they are not identical, so the issues on the sign of $s$ could be messing it up again, so caution if you use it.

Since more *weird functions* (non-linear for our purpose) have popped out from the Owen's T function (for the formula I give or also for the W-A answer), I was reviewing if this other version of the Owen´s T function was a bit easier for working with it: when viewing the the series expansion (Taylor) of $T\left[\sqrt{2}sx;\frac{1}{s}\right]$ on the variable $x$ at $x=1$ on [Wolfram-Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=series+OwenT%5Bsqrt%282%29*s*x%2C+1%2Fs%5D+at+x%3D1), it results it is given by a polynomial $T\left[\sqrt{2}s;\frac{1}{s}\right]+\mathbb{P}(x,s,\text{erf(1)}) \equiv T\left[\sqrt{2}s;\frac{1}{s}\right]+\mathbb{P}(x,s)$ so now the error functions on the coefficients of the series are given only by polynomials of $x$ and $s$, constants $\text{erf}(x=1)$ and a term $T\left[\sqrt{2}s;\frac{1}{s}\right]$ independent of the variable $x$, which maybe could be faster to compute than the series for $T[\sqrt{2}x,s]$.

I don´t know if it really useful, or even if applicable to the Chebyshev polynomials you are using, but since it looks interesting to me I have asked if you have tried it, but more for curiosity than for giving an answer.

Comment: I too was puzzled as WolframAlpha doesn't say what the T is so I asked around and most people didn't know either, finally I was told that this is Owen's T function, which is an integral with which I'm not sure what I would do.

Comment: @Michel Rouzic I tried the computation of the integral using $\arctan$, $\mathrm{erf}$ and Owen's T function as suggested by Wolfram Alpha and that *seems to work* just fine (spot checks only). Boost provides an implementation of Owen's T-Function called `owens_t()`, but I used the Fortran code from Mike Patefield, David Tandy, "Fast and accurate Calculation of Owen's T-Function", *Journal of Statistical Software* 5 (2000): 1-25. The performance of this is likely to be significantly lower than with your current approach, though.

Comment: Thank you, it's quite interesting than Owen's T function is so closely related to my problem. However that also means it does little to help with my problem, since the problem is still approximating such a function. The Padé approximation given above has an absolute error of about 0.032 in the corners, despite being a rather beefy polynomial. I think it's hard to beat decomposition by Chebyshev polynomials since it spreads the error so evenly, unlike Taylor series or Padé approximation.

Comment: Interesting problem, isn't it ? I am not been convinced at all by the performances of the Fortran code from Mike Patefield, David Tandy (for me, it is not so accurate). Do you have an idea about what could be "my" $a_n(z)$ ? Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Can "not so accurate" be expressed more precisely? I have not checked the `T()` implementation due to Patefield & Tandy rigorously, but for the modest argument ranges required in the context of this question, I observed from 13 to 15 correct decimal digits. I compiled with the Intel Fortran compiler (which provides very accurate $\mathrm{erf}$ and $\mathrm{erfc}$ implementations) using the strictest floating-point settings (`/fp:strict`).

Comment: "needing that much precision seems commonly that you are focusing maybe too much on this detail"
Not really, the whole polygon-rendering algorithm that makes use of this integral is already done and because the approximation of this integral is used 8 times for a tetragon (and all 8 results must visibly cancel each other to near zero far outside of the polygon) the approximation errors easily add up to visible artifacts with lesser precision. I was originally aiming for less precision but the artifacts were really visibly showing. I'll let you know about your latest method later today.

Comment: In the very restricted ranges, I agree with you.  I used this code with random numbers and had some "bad" results. Moreover, the calculations are not unexpensive at all. This is what I was trying to mean. Cheers :-)

Comment: @Joako That would be great if your expression was correct, however $\frac{\arctan(s)}{4\pi}+\frac{\arctan(1/s)}{4\pi} = \frac{\operatorname{sgn}(s)}{8}$, and the whole expression is equal to $\frac{\operatorname{sgn}(s)-1}{8}$, so unfortunately I'm afraid there's something quite wrong with it. See shorturl.at/eghoD (WolframAlpha link)

Comment: Unless there's an easy way to evaluate Owen's T using a combination of error functions (I guess the answer is no after all?) I guess focusing on it doesn't help since it seems that Owen's T represents the other part of the cone I'm interested in (which is why the difference with $\frac{\arctan(s)}{2\pi}$, which is the full Gaussian-weighted area of the cone from the origin, is equal to my integral) so approximating Owen's T or my integral is essentially almost the same problem.

Comment: @MichelRouzic did you tried series for $T[\sqrt{2}sx;\,1/s]$? They left only constants inside the $\text{erf}(x)$ functions when tested on point different from $x=0$, at least they look a bit easier to work with.

Comment: @Joako I'm not sure what that would develop into.

Comment: @MichelRouzic I have put what I was thinking when I made the question at the end of the answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

The problem being  $s \neq1$, may be, we could try
$$\text{erf}(ts)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi }}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{t^{2 n+1}}{(2 n+1) \, n!} s^{2n+1}$$ which would give
$$\int_0^x \frac{\operatorname{erf}(t s) \exp(-t^2)}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\, dt=\frac 1{2\pi}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{\Gamma (n+1)-\Gamma \left(n+1,x^2\right)}{(2 n+1) \Gamma (n+1)}s^{2n+1}$$

Computing the partial sums for $s=\frac 12$ and $x=2$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & \sum_{n=0}^p \\
 0 & 0.078119959 \\
 1 & 0.072095800 \\
 2 & 0.072853673 \\
 3 & 0.072753041 \\
 4 & 0.072765861 \\
 5 & 0.072764343 \\
 6 & 0.072764508 \\
 7 & 0.072764491 \\
 8 & 0.072764493
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit** (*after @Joako's answer*)

Let $t=\frac T s$ and using Mathematica on Wolfram Cloud gives immediately

$$\int_0^x \frac{\operatorname{erf}(t s) \exp(-t^2)}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\, dt=\frac{\tan ^{-1}(s)}{2 \pi }-\text{OwenT}\left[x\sqrt{2} ,s\right]$$ as already given by @Joako.

Expanded as a  series around $x=0$
$$\text{OwenT}\left[x\sqrt{2} ,s\right]=\frac{e^{-x^2} }{2 \pi }\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{b_n}{n!} x^{2n}$$
$$b_0=\tan ^{-1}(s) \qquad \text{and} \qquad b_{n}=b_{n-1}+(-1)^{n}\frac{ s^{2 n-1}}{2 n-1}$$

Suppose that we just take the expansion to $O(x^6)$ to make
$$F(x)=\frac{e^{-x^2}}{2 \pi }\Bigg[\tan ^{-1}(s)+ \left(\tan ^{-1}(s)-s\right)x^2+\frac{s^3-3 s+3 \tan^{-1}(s)}{6} x^4 \Bigg]$$

Computing
$$\Phi(s)=\int _{-3}^{+3} \Big[\text{OwenT}\left[x\sqrt{2},s\right]-F(x) \Big]^2\,dx$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
s & \Phi(s) \\
 0.1 & 4.438\times 10^{-19} \\
 0.2 & 6.694\times 10^{-15} \\
 0.3 & 1.709\times 10^{-12} \\
 0.4 & 8.020\times 10^{-11} \\
 0.5 & 1.467\times 10^{-9}  \\
 0.6 & 1.469\times 10^{-8}  \\
 0.7 & 9.673\times 10^{-8}  \\
 0.8 & 4.688\times 10^{-7}  \\
 0.9 & 1.800\times 10^{-6}  \\
 1.0 & 5.759\times 10^{-6}
\end{array}
\right)$$

Using the expansion up to $n=7$, the results are

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
s & \Phi(s) \\
 0.1 & 1.769 \times 10^{-35} \\
 0.2 & 3.047 \times 10^{-30} \\
 0.3 & 2.554 \times 10^{-24} \\
 0.4 & 3.685 \times 10^{-20} \\
 0.5 & 5.672 \times 10^{-17} \\
 0.6 & 2.102 \times 10^{-14} \\
 0.7 & 2.909 \times 10^{-12} \\
 0.8 & 1.957 \times 10^{-10} \\
 0.9 & 7.598 \times 10^{-9}  \\
 1.0 & 1.918 \times 10^{-7}
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Update**

We can easily build $P_m(x)$, the $[2m,2m]$ Padé approximant  of
$$2 \pi  e^{x^2} \text{OwenT}\left[x\sqrt{2} ,s\right]$$ which is, at least, $O(x^{4m+2})$. Have a look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=PadeApproximant%5B2*Pi*E%5Ex%5E2*OwenT%5BSqrt%5B2%5D*x%2C+s%5D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C%7B4%2C4%7D%7D%5D) for an example

Computing again the norm
$$\Phi_m(s)=\int _{-3}^{+3} \Big[\text{OwenT}\left[\sqrt{2} x,s\right]-P_m(x) \Big]^2\,dx$$ and reporting the results in a logarithmic scale
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
s & \log_{10}\Big[\Phi_2(s)\Big]& \log_{10}\Big[\Phi_3(s)\Big]& \log_{10}\Big[\Phi_4(s)\Big] \\
 0.1 & -28.98 & -38.71 & -\infty  \\
 0.2 & -22.49 & -29.85 & -36.99 \\
 0.3 & -18.82 & -24.84 & -30.62 \\
 0.4 & -16.34 & -21.46 & -26.29 \\
 0.5 & -14.53 & -18.99 & -23.12 \\
 0.6 & -13.14 & -17.11 & -20.70 \\
 0.7 & -12.04 & -15.63 & -18.79 \\
 0.8 & -11.16 & -14.45 & -17.25 \\
 0.9 & -10.43 & -13.48 & -16.00 \\
 1.0 & -9.820 & -12.69 & -14.95
\end{array}
\right)$$ which seems to be much better.

**Update**
We can also write
$$\frac{\tan ^{-1}(s)}{2 \pi }-\text{OwenT}\left[x\sqrt{2} ,s\right]=\frac{s x^2}{2 \pi } e^{-x^2}\Bigg[1+3\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac 1{n!} \frac{a_n}{b_n} x^{2n}\Bigg]$$ where the first $b_n$ are
$$\{2,15,140,525,6930,105105\}$$ and the $a_n$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & s^2-3 \\
 2 & 3 s^4-5 s^2+15 \\
 3 & 15 s^6-21 s^4+35 s^2-105 \\
 4 & 35 s^8-45 s^6+63 s^4-105 s^2+315 \\
 5 & 315 s^{10}-385 s^8+495 s^6-693 s^4+1155 s^2-3465 \\
 6 & 3465 s^{12}-4095 s^{10}+5005 s^8-6435 s^6+9009 s^4-15015 s^2+45045
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thank you, this is an interesting approach and it's simpler than it looks to implement. Unfortunately while it gives very high precision at low values of $x$ and $s$ it converges too slowly at the corners, with $p=4$,  $s$ near 1 and $x$ near 3 we get an absolute error close to 0.0015, all while taking a lot more than operations than a 31 coefficients polynomial. The way it converges fast close to the origin and too slowly further away reminds me of how Taylor series do something similar. Maybe the polynomials given by $\Gamma(n+1,x^2)$ can be modified to spread out the error?

Comment: Excellent, your $F(x)$ looks like a winner. I tested it and get a max absolute error of 0.00185 at $x=\pm1.625$ and $s=\pm1$, and higher precision along $x=\pm3$, which is quite desirable for my application. What would it look like if expanded to $O(x^7)$ or higher? I'm asking both because I'd like more precision but also I'm thinking that there may be a way to tweak the polynomial to better spread the error.

Comment: @MichelRouzic. I shall do the same withe all given terms and I shall edit the results.

Comment: @MichelRouzic. Done.

Comment: Unfortunately this approach converges very slowly, going from $O(x^6)$ to $O(x^{10})$ barely helps in the higher error areas while making the formula much heavier. $F(x)$ exactly how you wrote it is a great approach if the lower level of precision is acceptable, but higher orders wouldn't be competitive. May I ask how you obtained $b_n$? I'm perplexed by the mix of $s$ and $T$, it could be easy to improve on the polynomials if only one of the two was used, I don't understand how come $T$ is only for the lower degree.

Comment: @MichelRouzic. $T=\tan ^{-1}(s)-s$ was introduced just to shorten notations. I am working on a possible improvement.

Comment: I'm afraid the logical conclusion of the direction we're going is this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4380007/192968. We're going from decomposing the problem into a sum to optimising that approach by taking the function to fit, applying a few transformations to it then doing some generic fitting (be it Padé or Chebyshev). The next step is realising that the transformations we're applying (subtracting to the arctan and dividing by the Gaussian function, which have costs) don't help with getting a fit with fewer coefficients so then we end up with something simpler just like my answer.

Comment: That does look better with the $b_n$ recursion, but are you sure it's written correctly? Because it gives me $b_1 = b_0 - \frac{1}{s}$, and $b_2 = b_1 - s$, which is markedly different from what your expansion gives us.

Comment: @MichelRouzic. It gives $b_1=b_0-s$ and $b_2=b_1+\frac 13 s^3$.

Comment: Then please explain where I'm getting it wrong. You wrote $b_{n+1} = b_n + (-1)^n \frac{s^{2n-1}}{2n-1}$ which gives you $b_1 = b_0 + (-1)^0 \frac{s^{0-1}}{-1} = b_0 + \frac{s^{-1}}{-1} = b_0 - s^{-1}$. I think you meant $b_{n} = b_{n-1} + (-1)^n \frac{s^{2n-1}}{2n-1}$ or $b_{n+1} = b_n + (-1)^{n+1} \frac{s^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$, right?

Comment: @MichelRouzic. You are right ! Mistake in typing (this happens - rmember that I am blind). Sorry fot that & cheers :-(

Comment: Thanks. Sadly while it's very efficient for going up to low values of $n$, more iterations fail to bring the error in the corners low enough, which translate into visible artifacts, even when going up to $n=9$. Your answer is the only one that pushed the Pareto efficiency at least for lower precisions compared to my approach though.

Answer (score 1):

I'll keep track of my current best approach. In the question I mentioned my best answer being a simple 31-coefficient polynomial. I just found something a bit better for the same precision, an 18-coefficient polynomial:
$$z = (((((-1.6663128{\times}10^{-5}s^2 + 5.104393{\times}10^{-6})x^2 + 0.0005496131s^2 - 5.30433{\times}10^{-5})x^2 + (0.0001584783s^2 - 0.00741157237)s^2 - 0.0018265954)x^2 +(-0.003881739s^2 + 0.0523013844)s^2 + 0.04582956)x^2 + ((-0.00368418s^2 + 0.03692744)s^2 - 0.1996548)s^2 - 0.50360028)x^2 + ((-0.0012717s^2 - 0.0101518)s^2 + 0.0109084)s^2 - 1.836892$$

to which a few operations are applied:

$$\int_0^x \frac{\operatorname{erf}(t s) \exp(-t^2)}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\, dt \approx x^2 s \exp(z)$$

The polynomial was fitted to this function $g(x,s)$:

$$f(x,s) = \int_0^x \frac{\operatorname{erf}(t s) \exp(-t^2)}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\, dt$$
$$g(x,s) = \log(\frac{f(\sqrt x,s)}{xs})$$
in the range $x=[0.4,9.2]$ and $s=[-1,1]$ with 2D Chebyshev polynomials with Chebyshev coefficients under $3{\times}10^{-4}$ culled.

Comment: @njuffa I don't use such "optimisations" because all they do is make most areas worse just to make a few areas a bit better. In this case I tweaked the fitting areas so that there would be less precision at low values of $x$ and good precision at the edges of $x$, because for this application this is what matters.

Comment: I don't think you understand my point. Such optimisations are desirable if you only care about lowering the number that is the max absolute error at any cost, the cost is making the areas with lower error have much worse error just to make the max error go down a little bit. In this application I do not care to minimise the max error if it makes visible visual artifacts worse, which is what happens here. If people mindlessly systematically use minimax approximations it's because they don't know better, maybe they don't even know what their approximation's error even looks like before and after

Comment: @njuffa Interesting, thanks for checking. Interesting because it's kind of coincidental, I didn't mean to make it like this.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a sum of squared quadratic exponentials approximation to the error function, including linear terms in the quadratics:
$$
\widehat{\Phi}_M(t;\,\{a_i,b_i,c_i\})=1-\sum_{i=1}^{M} c_i \exp(-a_i t^2+2b_i t),~t\geq 0
$$
which has $3M$ parameters to be estimated, namely the $\{a_i,b_i,c_i\}$, $i=1,\ldots,M$ with $a_i>0$ $\forall i$. The approximation is valid for nonnegative t, then extended to the real line using the odd symmetry of the error function ${\rm erf}(-t)=-{\rm erf}(t)$. Note that this approximator can be made exact at $t=0$.

Leaving aside the question of the approximation parameters, we can plug in the appoximator into the integral in question
$$
I(x,s)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^x {{\rm erf}}(t s) \exp(-t^2)\, dt
$$
to obtain
$$
I(x,s)\approx \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^x\exp(-t^2)\, dt-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}
\sum_{i=1}^{M} c_i \int_0^x \exp(-a_is^2t^2+2b_ist)\exp(-t^2)\, dt
$$
which simplifies to
$$
I(x,s)\approx \frac{1}{4}{\rm erf}(x)
-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}
\sum_{i=1}^{M} c_i \int_0^x \exp(-\alpha_i^2t^2+2\beta_it)\, dt
$$
where we have defined $\alpha_i^2=1+a_i s^2$ and $\beta_i=b_i s$.
The integral above is standard, even in the indefinite case, and according to 2.33(1) of Gradshteyn and Ryzhik's "Table of Integrals, Series and Products," we have (for $\alpha\neq 0$, with $\alpha>0$ here):
$$
\int \exp(-\alpha^2t^2+2\beta t)\, dt=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\alpha}\exp\left(\frac{\beta^2}{\alpha^2}\right){\rm erf}\left(\alpha t-\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\right)
$$
Therefore we get an approximator of the form
$$
I(x,s)\approx \frac{1}{4}{\rm erf}(x)
-\sum_{i=1}^{M} \frac{c_i}{4\alpha_i}
\exp\left((\beta_i/\alpha_i)^2\right)
\left[
{\rm erf}\left(\alpha_ix-\frac{\beta_i}{\alpha_i}\right)+
{\rm erf}\left(\frac{\beta_i}{\alpha_i}\right)
\right]
$$
This approximator only requires $M$ exponential and $2M+1$ error function evaluations and is a direct approximation - not piecewise for the entire parameter region in $x$ and $s$.

Now the interesting part: how to obtain the coefficients $\{a_i,b_i,c_i\}$, $i=1,\ldots,M$? This is the subject of a current paper I have in review and I can't give full details here at the moment, suffice to say it is not difficult - a simple gradient descent is used to optimise them. I have obtained the coefficients for the $M=4$ case and the fit to the error function over the range $0\leq x\leq 4$ has a peak absolute relative error (ARE) of about $7E-4$ for $x\in[0,4]$, which immediately extends to $[-4,4]$ due to erf being an odd function. This should give a better accuracy under integration, maybe around $1E-5$. The $M=4$ coefficients are listed below. If these do not provide the required accuracy for the integral, one could move to $M=5$, which would probably do the trick.

$a_1,\ldots,a_4$:  $+1.102149$,  $+0.602149$,  $+0.802149$,  $+0.302149$

$b_1,\ldots,b_4$:  $-0.738479$,  $-0.738479$,  $-0.638479$,  $-0.238479$

$c_1,\ldots,c_4$:  $-0.656344$,  $-8.65439E\!-\!2$,  $+1.742885$, $2.31093E\!-\!6$

The context of this work is the study of low-dimensional generative adversarial networks (GANs) based on error function integrals. Please refer to https://www.researchgate.net/publication/356815736_Convergence_and_Optimality_Analysis_of_Low-Dimensional_Generative_Adversarial_Networks_using_Error_Function_Integrals

Comment: Thank you, it's interesting that you were able to break down the problem into this form, however you still need 9 error functions evaluations. It sounds like in terms of performance your own application could use an approach like this one https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4380007/192968 which is computationally much less demanding.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has a good discussion on the so-called error function including some approximation formulas [available here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).

I have employed one of the series approximation  in a spreadsheet calculation with good results.

You must, for your problem, combine the above into a good numerical analysis routine to approximate the value of integral.

Good luck (as it is a process of trial and error).

Comment: I don't see how approximating the error function would help with this problem, maybe you should elaborate.

Comment: Because the numerical analysis part needs a computation at various increments of the function under the integral sign.  Here is an introduction as provided by Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration. He may wish also to consult a text book on "Numerical Analysis" for more complex and hopefully more accurate paths. But again, case dependent.

Comment: I see what you mean. I thought about it but concluded that even though I have an $\operatorname{erf}$ implementation equivalent to about 9 multiply-adds (which is pretty good, see https://github.com/Photosounder/rouziclib/blob/master/rouziclib/graphics/drawqueue/opencl/gaussian.cl#L6) this means that I could only evaluate $\operatorname{erf}$ twice to perform better than my current solution of using a 2D polynomial with 31 coefficients. I really don't think we can reach my target of precision by using only two increments to integrate.

Comment: I was sure that I missed something. Now, it is much simpler.